# Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, php-deployer

I'm using [Deployer](https://github.com/deployphp/deployer) for deploying my code to multiple servers. Today I got this error after starting a deployment:

```
[Deployer\Exception\RuntimeException (-1)]                                                        
The command "if hash command 2>/dev/null; then echo 'true'; fi" failed.                           
Exit Code: -1 (Unknown error)                                                                     
Host Name: staging                                                                                
================                                                                                  
Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.  
Permission denied (publickey).
```

First I thought it would probably has something to do with this server configuration since I moved the complete installation to another hosting provider. I tried to trigger a deployment to a server which I deployed to just fine in the past days but then got the same error. This quickly turned my suspicions from server to local.

Since I'm running PHP in docker (Deployer is written in PHP), I thought it might had something to do with my ssh-agent not being forwarded correctly from my host OS to docker. I verified this by using a fresh PHP installation directly from my OS (Ubuntu if that would help). Same warning kept popping up in the logs.

When logging in using the `ssh` command everything seems to be alright. I still have no clue what going on here. Any ideas?

PS: I also created an issue at Deployer's GIT repo: https://github.com/deployphp/deployer/issues/1507

Comment: I'm not clear what the actual problem is here. The error message seems clear enough, it's saying that a certain SSH key file doesn't exist. Does the file actually exist? Is it supposed to exist, and is ssh supposed to be using that key file? Or is ssh supposed to be getting ssh keys from somewhere else?

Comment: My apologies. I forgot to mention this key does actually exist and it is supposed to exist. Deployer needs this key to authenticate at the server where my git repo is located, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with the library you are talking about, but the issue starts here:

```
Warning: Identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

So let's focus on that. Potential things I can think of:

1. Is the username really `user`? It says that the file lives at: `/home/user`. Verifying that that really is the correct path. For instance, just `ls` the file. If it doesn't exist, you will get an error:

   $ ls /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

That will throw a `No such file or directory` if it doesn't exist.

2. If 1. is not the issue, then most likely this is a user issue where the permissions are wrong for the user in the Docker container. If this is the issue, then INSIDE the Docker container, change the permissions on `id_rsa` before you need to do it:

   ```
   $ chmod 600 /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
   Now do stuff with the key...
   ```

A lot of SSH agents won't work unless the key is only read-write accessible by the user who is trying to run the ssh agent. In this case, that is the user inside of the Docker container.